# Return list of index of two lists given a third list

Tags: python, list

What is the smartest and most pythonic way to achieve this please:

input:

```
i1 = [A,A,B]
i2 = [x,y,x]
i3 = [0,1,2]
```

parameter:

```
list = [[A,x],[B,x],[A,y]]
```

(or `list = [[A,B,A],[x,z,y]]` if easier)

One needs to find the index `idx` when list matches i1 and i2 and output `i3[idx]`

output:

```
output = [0,2,1]
```

I was thinking about list comprehensions to find all occurences of (element1,element2) in i1 and i2 but I can't manage to do it:

```
idxs = [i for i,v in enumerate(zip(i1,i2)) if v==(x[0],x[1]) for x in list]
```

Comment: Why can't it be `output = [0,0,1]` as `x` occurs twice?

Comment: ```output = [i3[list(zip(i1,i2)).index(tuple(item))] for item in l]``` with ```l``` as your input (```l = [[A,x],[B,x],[A,y]]```) works! It's a pretty specific question and thereby answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comprehension was very close,

Here I'm using an almost identical one to create a dictionary mapping a pair to an index, and then just get the indexes from it:

```py
i1 = ['A','A','B']
i2 = ['x','y','x']

d = {tup: idx for idx,tup in enumerate(zip(i1,i2))}

list = [['A','x'],['B','x'],['A','y']]

result = [d[tuple(pair)] for pair in list]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: note: this assumes the input lists contains only legal pairs, otherwise you'd get a `KeyError`

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is by using a dictionary:

```py
i1 = ['A','A','B']
i2 = ['x','y','x']
i3 = [0,1,2]
list = [['A','x'],['B','x'],['A','y']]

mapping = dict(zip(zip(i1, i2), i3))
out = [mapping[tuple(e)] for e in list]
print(out)
```

```
[0, 2, 1]
```